# Is there a way for a single GPU and model to run deep learning model prediction/inference in parallel

Tags: python, deep-learning, quantization

If there's a 8G-RAM GPU, and has loaded a model that takes all the 8G RAM, is it possible to run multiple model prediction/inference in parallel?

or you can only run a prediction at a same time period

Comment: if someone is already working 24 hours a day, can he work another job ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If your single model uses all 8gb of RAM, then it would not be possible to run another model in parallel using the same resources. You would have to allocate more memory or schedule the second model to run afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to use Batching if you are working only with a single model but have multiple samples to run inference/prediction on. You could group individual pred-jobs into one batched at some interval (time-wise, or case-wise). this will introduce definitively a delay for each individual prediction-task but will make your distributed predictions-task more efficient ovral